# Deleted ubuntu EFI

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2, grub-efi

With a pretty red face I am trying to recover my Deepin install.

I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed but wanted to try something different. When I previously removed Ubuntu from my windows dual boot I had to manually remove the ubuntu EFI directory to stop the system launching in the boot menu everytime. Like a moron I tried to do the same with my linux only machine and now everytime I boot I just get:

GNU GRUB version 2.02~berta2-36ubuntu2

I tried just exiting using the exit command but then I just get a message saying install a proper boot device.

I tried to enter failsafe mode from the deepin boot drive to add the efi file back in but I think this is just a live mode so everytime I reboot the ubuntu directory is gone again.

Is there any way to overcome this short of a reinstall? Can I somehow just get the ubuntu efi directory back in there from GRUB or something?

I have now gone through the recovery process as per the comment with Boot-Repair and it still boots in gnu grub.

Comment: Probably a job for https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair from a Live-USB...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

Answer (score 1):

Since the efi ubuntu directory has been deleted you would have to copy the efi files from a live cd of the same version as your current ubuntu

So lets first Boot into a live cd of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS . 
*Sometimes other versions of ubuntu would work but don't use another distro to do the live cd*

open your terminal and list the partitions on your computer

```
lsblk
```

yOu get something like

```
sda            8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1         8:1    0 601.4G  0 part 
├─sda2         8:2    0 325.2G  0 part 
└─sda3         8:3    0   200M  0 part 
sr1           11:1    1  1024M  0 rom  
sdb
├─sdb1         8:1    0 4.4G  0 part /media/user/pendrive
```

Guess your **linux ext4 filesytem**, sdXY . In this case mine was sda1. Replace it with your own

Now we should mount the linux filesystem:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

mount some other required things:

```
for i in  /dev  /dev/pts  /proc  /sys  /run; do sudo mount -B $i  /mnt$i; done
```

Now chroot into the mounted partition.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

You should now be in your old ubuntu filesystem

Now Create the directory where grub would install the files:

```
# mkdir -p /boot/efi
```

lets identify our EFI partition:

```
lsblk
```

it is usually around 100MB or 200MB. Mine was sda3. I would be representing it  using sdxy. The disk is sda.

Now mount the efi partition:

```
# mount /dev/sdxy /boot/efi
```

Install grub to the disk:

```
# apt install efibootmgr
# grub-install /dev/sdX
```

grub would install all the nessary efi files required to boot your PC

After installing grub do:

```
# update-grub
```

When you are done exit the chroot:

```
# exit
```

Now reboot:

```
reboot
```

Hopefully this should fix it

Comment: Thanks ptetteh, really in-depth answer and much appreciated