# Deleted EFI partition and now no OS detected while booting

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, 20.04, disk

I deleted /dev/sda1 partition of Ubuntu 20.04 by mistake, now when I try to boot, system is not able to detect the OS, is there any way to fix this ?
This the image of disks using live usb
[image: the partition which I delted]
[image: another partition which contains all the files]

I have tried various approaches mentioned in various articles including using boot repair, but nothing fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried creating a FAT32 partition where sda1 was and rerunning boot repair?

Comment: yes, I created the fat32 partition while running boot repair, but that didn't work.

Comment: I think this link should provide the answer. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028375/deleted-ubuntu-efi
The answer below will leave you with two installations which I wouldn’t recommend

Comment: @PonJar I tried this but in the step of installing grub `grub-install /dev/sda` I am getting error `grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition` Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: I think an EFI partition needs to be marked as ESP. You should be able to do that with GParted. My EFI partition is flagged “boot, esp”

Comment: I did `mount /dev/sda1 /boot/efi` again after the error and tried again installing grub and it worked. I am now able to boot. Thanks a lot for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @PonJar for the link.
Using [askubuntu.com/questions/1028375/deleted-ubuntu-efi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028375/deleted-ubuntu-efi)
I was able to fix it.
If you face this error `grub-install: error: /boot/efi doesn't look like an EFI partition` during grub installation step, just do `mount /dev/sdaxy /boot/efi` again. This will fix it.

Comment: So you did not delete root partition? Just EFI?

Comment: yes, the EFI was deleted.

Comment: Please edit the title of the question to "deleted EFI" instead of "deleted one of the partitions" as it may be more helpful to future users who might have the same problem