# Wierd "flickering" once starting ubuntu using the grub bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, bootloader

I have very recently succeeded in installing Ubuntu as a dual-boot to my windows 10.

However, when I start ubuntu using the grub bootloader, a weird thing is happening to my screen.

It is hard to explain, so here's a picture of it: https://ibb.co/p1JKYrj
I can still hear the sounds of ubuntu as I interact with the keyboard, but my screen is just stuck.

I have tried putting my computer to "sleep mode" and then waking it again. Once I do this, I get past the screen and can enter ubuntu with no trouble at all.  I think it would be very annoying for me to have to put my pc in sleep-mode and wake it again in order for me to start ubuntu.

Does anyone have a solution to this trouble?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc Your answer is here.

Comment: It works fine when i select Windows using the grub bootloader, Windows boots without any trouble.

So is it really grub that is broken?