# Update Ubuntu Studio 18.04 --> 20.04 failed / stuck, will not go into GUI

Tags: networking, updates, 20.04, internet

I hope you can help me.
Last night I started my laptop (running Ubuntu Studio 18.04) and got a message if I wanted to upgrade to version 20.04. I startet die Update, and it ran the whole night. This Morning, it showed the message that it had finished and I should reboot the machine to finish the update. I did that.
Now, whenever I try to start the machine, it does not go into the GUI, but I get a command prompt for my Login and Password. After I enter my Login and PW, it says "Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 [...] 0 updates can be installed immediately. 0 of these updates are security updates. Failed to connect to https://chengelog.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your internet connection or proxy settings"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0EPh.jpg)

And now I am stuck there. What can I do? I have been searching the internet for 1 1/2 hours now, but could not find anything that helped me.

Usually the laptop is in WLAN, but I also tried connecting an ethernet cable directly to my router. But when I try to ping anything it says the network is not connected, I also see no activity from the LEDs on the LAN-Port.

(Sorry, I am a noob to Linux, I just installed Ubuntu Studio a few months ago on this laptop, because I only use it as an occasional backup and did not want to buy a windows 10 license to upgrade a 13 year old machine)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you can boot a live USB of Ubuntu, does this answer your question?
[boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

Comment: I did that. After a password promt is scrolled whole bunch of text, at the end it said "0 upgraded, 561 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need to get 287 MB of archives. After this operation, 1.047 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue?" 
I clicked "yes", then it scrolled a bunch more text again. I will get back to you when it has finished.

Comment: Okay, it finished, looks like it got a lot of errors "temporary failure resolving 'de.archive.ubuntu.com' "
Screenshot: https://up.picr.de/39320345yy.jpg

Comment: Ah, so you are not connected to the internet... try this command `sudo systemctl isolate graphical`

Comment: Okay, I did that. It asked me to put in my password - I did that - and then it just went back to the normal command prompt (kevin@AsusLaptop2007:~$)
Edit: Afterwards I tried running the install from above again, same result, seems to be unable to connect to the web.

Comment: What is the output of `ls /usr/bin/*session` because if we know the desktop environment we may be able to start it manually. In the meantime, use another PC to create a bootable USB with the 20.04 iso on it, this might end up being the only way to rescue the upgrade.

Comment: entering "ls /usr/bin/*session" gives me an output of "/usr/bin/dbus-run-session" in green text. With a "bootable USB of the ISO" you mean the normal USB image that I also would use if I wanted to do a new install of the OS, right?

Comment: So there is no desktop installed yet, so we cannot kick-start it. Re the USB: Yes. When you boot to that USB with you can choose **Try Ubuntu** and you will get a desktop. From here we might get the internet connection back or at least use the terminal to determine if all your data is still safe.

Comment: hello darth, I have the USB-Image set up now and managed to boot into the "trial" GUI. With that, I re-connected to my WiFi-Network and now have internet access. I am still getting no access over LAN, not sure if the LAN-Adapter in that Laptop still works, or maybe it needs additional drivers (I have never used the laptop on LAN since I converted it to Linux).
What would be the next step now?

Re: data loss: Luckily there isn't really any important "data" on that machine, but it would be a pain in the ass if I had to do the whole setup again, after I finally got it working like I wanted.

Comment: I followed the instruction and ran the boot repair tool according to them.
Then I rebooted the system.
Now when I turn on the PC, it says "Checking NVRAM" or something like that for a split second, then just goes to a black screen and does absolutely nothing (for a moment I can see some hard drive activity, and then that is gone, too).

I guess I'll have to wipe everything and install everything from scratch now?

Comment: Can you boot again with the USB and get the "Try Ubuntu" desktop?

Comment: Hello Darth, I can boot with the "try Ubuntu" on the stick, but after I tried your suggestion with the boot repair tool the normal boot was completely broken (would not even load into a commad promt, just a black screen). So I have now wiped everything and did a fresh install. But thank you for the help anyway.