# "The selected boot device failed."

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I've been using a dual booted pc with Ubuntu and Windows 10 for about 2 years now. However, all of a sudden when I turned on my computer today, I got the following message:

```
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to open image \EFI\Ubuntu\grub64.efi: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

After two seconds of this message, I get the following message in blue in the center of the screen:

```
The selected boot device failed. Press <Enter> to Continue.
```

This is very odd since I haven't really done anything out of the ordinary or configure anything on my system...

When going to the Boot Option Menu, and select the windows boot manager, I am able boot up windows 10 just fine without any problem.

I need my ubuntu back! As well as the files I have on there!

Anyone have any idea how this happened and how I can fix this issue?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Did Windows do an update and turn fast start up back on. Or an UEFI update and reset UEFI to defaults including turning UEFI Secure Boot back on? Check settings.

Comment: Secure boot was enabled and I disabled it. Also fast start up is on. I'm not sure if there was an UEFI update or not. But I didn't do any manual updates.

Comment: Fast Startup can cause the drive to go into a Read Only mode for Linux to read which might cause boot problems.  Make sure that Fast Startup is disabled in Windows.  Also, if you are disabling that, there is also the possibility that the `hiberfil.sys` file still exists on the partition which will cause Linux to set it in Read Only as well.  To get rid of that file from a cmd window as Administrator in Windows you run `powercfg -h off` to turn off Hibernation.

Comment: I disabled Fast Startup and turned off Hibernation. But I'm still running into the same exact error. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!
What worked for me was creating a live USB disk with Ubuntu and then selecting the "try Ubuntu" option. From there I download the boot repair tool found here:

[How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

From the log of the boot repair it seems like all that was done was GRUB being reinstalled.

Lesson learned: back up your files in case stuff like this happens again...