# Stuck at initramfs, no results on exit command

Tags: boot, initramfs

On booting my 64 bit machine running ubuntu 20.04 I am getting the following error:

```
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.2-4ubuntu6.1 built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
```

Most solution available on the internet suggest to hit the 'exit' command and expect to find some errors. In my case when I hit the exit command I don't get anything. See below:

```
(initramfs) exit

BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.2-4ubuntu6.1 built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) _
```

Could anybody help me to how to get out of this and boot my machine normally?

Here is the photo of what I am getting.

[image]

Comment: Usually above the (initramfs) prompt there is a message as to why it stopped there.  Can you maybe add a photo of where it stopped at so we can see the full message you are getting?

Comment: @Terrance - I have added the screenshot. As mentioned in the question, I don't know what error has occured.

Comment: Try rebooting the system then take the pic again without typing anything in.  If that is what it comes to, then you might want to look into the Boot Repair App to fix your boot issue.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Comment: I did that. After hitting 'reboot -f' command, I get the first error as posted in the image above.

Comment: @Terrance - Sorry. I was responding to your suggestion of rebooting. I meant that I have tried rebooting but don't get to see any new error. I haven't tried the solutions you have suggested yet. Will try it and update if that solves the problem. Thank you for your support and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Ah, my bad.  Let us know if those suggestions don't work.  =)

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing Ubuntu 20.04+ using LVM or ZFS partition since this bug is related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660). You will find this option when you are prompted for installation type (clean install or not). If you select clean install and then go to advanced features, you will find the option to choose between LVM and ZFS. Selecting LVM (also checked with ZFS, but not recommended since ZFS is still in its experimental stage) solved my problem.