# My Ubuntu PC is not booting but it is keep booting the memtest

Tags: boot, memtest

I don't know what I did, but it is keep booting up memtest. What is wrong with it? Did it replace my bootloader?
Or how can I get my data back if so?

Comment: I would look into doing the Boot-Repair on your drive:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Comment: Memtest is an option in grub, usually further down the list.  Will need the ubuntu installer USB/DVD to repair grub as @Terrance said.