# BIOS cant detect HDD but Ubuntu installation can detect HDD every time

Tags: boot, grub2, hard-drive, uefi, bios

I have an i3 5th gen Asus laptop. It's around 3 to 4 years old. Lately, I am having boot problems with Windows 10 on it. So I decided to permanently move to Ubuntu 20.04. But I am having the same problem. When I press the power button OS not botting up and shows below error -

`Reboot and Select proper Boot device`
`or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key`

BIOS can't detect my HDD. But when I try to install from a USB stick Ubuntu can detect HDD every time without any issue. Also, Ubuntu installed successfully but did not boot up after reboot. Is there a fix? Or can I manually boot from HDD via another USB stick without BIOS?

S.M.A.R.T :

````
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MQ01ABD...
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100
Serial Number:    ********
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 6f2484d35
Firmware Version: AX0R2J
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Mar 31 05:52:14 2021 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (  120) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 239) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Always       -       1801
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1843
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   050    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       3376
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   136   100   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1830
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       817
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       49
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       17300
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 13/47)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       10193
220 Disk_Shift              0x0002   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
222 Loaded_Hours            0x0032   093   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       3115
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
224 Load_Friction           0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
226 Load-in_Time            0x0026   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       264
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0001   100   100   001    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 10910 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 10910 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3376 hours (140 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 10 2f 01 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000012f = 303

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 10 28 01 00 40 00      00:00:38.181  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 08 20 01 00 40 00      00:00:38.181  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 00 18 01 00 40 00      00:00:38.181  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 f0 10 01 00 40 00      00:00:38.181  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 b8 08 01 00 40 00      00:00:38.172  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 10909 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3376 hours (140 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 98 0f 01 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000010f = 271

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 98 08 01 00 40 00      00:00:37.749  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 90 f8 00 00 40 00      00:00:37.749  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 88 f0 00 00 40 00      00:00:37.749  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 80 e8 00 00 40 00      00:00:37.748  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 78 e0 00 00 40 00      00:00:37.748  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 10908 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3376 hours (140 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 30 2f 00 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x0000002f = 47

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 30 28 00 00 40 00      00:00:37.317  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 03 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:37.316  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:37.316  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:00:37.315  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:00:37.314  IDENTIFY DEVICE

Error 10907 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3376 hours (140 days + 16 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 90 37 00 00 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00000037 = 55

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 f8 a8 08 01 00 40 00      00:00:36.892  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 78 a0 88 00 00 40 00      00:00:36.892  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 30 98 48 00 00 40 00      00:00:36.892  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 10 90 28 00 00 40 00      00:00:36.892  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 88 10 00 00 40 00      00:00:36.892  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 10906 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 3375 hours (140 days + 15 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 41 38 6f 6b 70 40  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00706b6f = 7367535

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 38 68 6b 70 40 00      00:01:19.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 30 58 6b 70 40 00      00:01:19.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 28 50 6b 70 40 00      00:01:19.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 20 48 6b 70 40 00      00:01:19.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 18 40 6b 70 40 00      00:01:19.559  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.```
````

Comment: I suggest you validate the health of your hardware (esp. disk by checking it's SMART status using `smartctl`, `gnome-disks` or whichever tool you prefer),  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   It sounds like it needs replacement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check the SMART status of a SSD or HDD on current versions of Ubuntu 14.04 through 18.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1)

Comment: I added the S.M.A.R.T information. Can you please check?

Comment: Operating systems will not see a drive, that UEFI/BIOS does not see. So your UEFI sees the drive, but does not find correct boot. Could be you have UEFI Secure boot on, and only boot entry is not UEFI Secure or is BIOS boot. Or you have BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot on and it only finds UEFI boot. Check UEFI boot setting mode and Secure boot mode. Windows update and/or UEFI update may have reset UEFI settings to defaults. Windows with some systems also does UEFI update. Check all settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)