# Dual boot Ubuntu update from 20 to 22 failed with crash

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 22.04

I'm running a dual boot system
Grub is run on boot to select OS to load
The two OSs that can be selected are: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20
I booted into Ubuntu.  It ran fine and asked me If I wanted to Update to Ubuntu 22

During the update to Ubuntu 22 the PC crashed.

Booting to Windows 10 works fine.
Booting to Ubuntu starts but eventually hangs in text mode with just a blank screen and cursor.

If I use an Ubuntu Install dvd, the dvd install does not ask me to repair only to install.

I do not know how to proceed.  Any advice

Thanks :-)

Comment: first try this answer from this post:https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc.if it doesn't work,i'm afraid that you have might lost all your data. you have to boot windows, delete the ubuntu partitions and reinstall ubuntu alongside windows option during install.

Comment: The advice advice is a waste of time. Unfortunately many users don't understand the purpose of Boot Repair which is to install/reinstall Grub ONLY! If Grub works then there's no usage for Boot Repair. What happens after Grub is the problem in your case due to the failed release upgrade. Do NOT use DVD, the year is 2022, not 2002! Use a properly made USB live/installation media with Ubuntu 22.04 for repairs and yes, do proceed to the installation but choose "something else", select all the relevant partition but do NOT check format.

Comment: Better to try using the console (command line) and do a normal `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Do you get grub menu? Or press escape when booting Ubuntu between vendor screen & when grub normally appears. And then boot recovery mode? Often issues on upgrade relate to ppa or proprietary drivers that must be first disabled and then reinstalled once upgrade finishes. You do have good backup?

Comment: "you might have lost all your data" that's not quite true. Even if the system isn't booting, as long as the hard-disk and filesystem are fine you'll still be able to boot with a live USB, open the partition, and copy your important data elsewhere.

Comment: After trying a large number of Ubuntu re-installs with different versions and failing, I tried using the grub reinstall utility.  It found the Ubuntu install which was corrupted by the bad version 22 install and screwed up the Windows boot options.  So I installed Ubuntu 22 on the correct partitions.  Then I had to re-install Windows 10 from scratch.  So now I have only Windows 10 boot-able, Ubuntu 22 correctly installed but inaccessible.  I'm afraid to run the grub utility because I don't want to loose my Windows install again. Despite all this trouble I did not loose any data
Suggestions??