# recovery your pc/device needs to be repaired

Tags: boot, data-recovery

I had windows 10 trial version in my pc. I removed it and installed ubuntu (It is not a dual-boot). I did not have any problem with it for almost 2 months. But today suddenly when I am turning my PC on, I am getting this: Wondows Recovery Error in Ubuntu:

[image]

I am able to start it by pressing ESC and overriding to run Ubuntu, but even after saving, it is not getting saved. If anyone else have faced this issue, or know how to fix it, kindly help. I am new to ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like when you installed Ubuntu, you did not recovery partition for Windows. Now for some reason the computer is booting from that partition.

Comment: @user68186 So what is the solution for it. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't have a solution. See [this question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc) and [this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/) and try the recommended repair as shown in the tutorial. If it does not work, add a link to the pastebin where the boot=repair log is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this while installing Ubuntu on one of those mini pc's that come with Windows installed.

Before doing any of the following, make sure you have good backups, because a mistake can render your system unbootable.

Open a terminal and become superuser with `sudo su`, entering your password when prompted.

Browse to `/boot/efi`.  Now you are looking for a folder called `Microsoft` in one of the subfolders here. In mine it was called `EFI` so the folder is `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft`

Delete this folder, then update grub with an `update-grub` command.

Then reboot.

Comment: Thank You very much my friend. It worked. Actually even I am using one of those mini pc's. It had trial version of windows 10, that's why I decided to switch to Linux.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.