# Ubuntu Server 22.04 - Missing Network Adapters

Tags: 22.04

I have hit a brick wall and I don't know where else to turn. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let me start out by saving I am not too well-versed on Linux, I hate when people say this, but I know enough to be dangerous.. And just that, I was too dangerous.

On a workstation (Dell Optiplex 7040), I am running Docker and two containers for Wordpress and the Wordpress database.

I was getting low on drive storage, so I ran some command to remove unused applications, and I am afraid I may have removed all applications needed to see the ethernet adapter on my workstation. I am unable to ping any addresses, and my machine is not visible on my network anymore.

When I run any network-manager applications, the application cannot be found, same with any IP/IF commands. Since this workstation has no access to the internet, how can I correct this probem?

Is there any way I can create a bootable disk, and just install the needed/missing applications?

Someone please help me, and please talk to me like I am a 7-year-old-child in terms of troubleshooting steps.

Comment: You can create a bootable disk using another computer ;-) I can see any troubleshooting steps based on this information.

Comment: But I would not lose any data?

Comment: You can boot from it and save all your data.

Comment: Creating a new bootable USB now. Does this seem like it would aide my problem? https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc

Comment: Boot repair won't help, because you don't have problems with booting.

Comment: Is there a way I can do an install on top of Ubuntu that would repair/reinstall any removed pertinent applications? Can you reference any articles to help?

Comment: It is unclear what you removed, that's the problem. Generally you can re-install with saving user information.

Comment: It appears I am missing network-manager, iproute2, libbpf0, isc-dhcp-common to name a few. Is there a .deb file somewhere that would reinstall these to where I can just put it on a USB and install them?

Comment: It's not that easy. There are a lot of packages with dependencies. It will take forever. The only feasible solution is to re-install.