# Upgrade 23.04 stops Dead

Tags: boot, upgrade

After upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 (from 22.10), 23.04 will not load after the restart, it just stops dead after the bios. I tried everything just to get it loaded, but it just stops, and that is the only way to explain it, no other info. It just stops. I don’t have a clue, does anyone else?

Comment: no error message, no GRUB, nothing? And the BIOS doesn't give any error regarding the boot disk?

Comment: You're going to need a bootable drive if this is fixable, [install boot repair on it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc), create a Boot Info summary, put it in a pastebin, and link that here so we can see what's going on

Comment: No error messages no grub and bios has nothing. Can I use a bootable flash drive?

Comment: yes, of course. That's what I put in my second comment.

Comment: Finally got something new,  and again it just stopped. I am trying to add a picture I took with my phone but it won’t let me add it in with my comment, but more or less here is what it is saying, (/dev/sda5:  recovery journal

Comment: And (/dev/sada5: clean, 290847/30162944 files, 10640759/120631296 blocks, and goes no further

Comment: You've provided almost no details; we don't know what product (Server? Desktop? *flavor*? etc)  Comments are for exactly that (*comments to the OP or Original Poster, or a prior commenter*) and not for additional details - this isn't a forum but a Q&A site, and Answers will be to the question itself (*not comments made to the OP*). Have you tried booting into *recovery* mode? or *runlevel 1*?  (both selected at `grub`).  If you have *pictures* provide the links in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It kept stopping right after the bios and before the grub menu, you know the black screen with the blinking cursor. Well to the point, all I had to do was hit the control and the super buttons and hit f6 twice, it will give you a login message, just hit enter, and you are in. Problem solved with an old trick. Thanks for the help guys.