# Ubuntu 22.04. does show black screen instead of login-screen after last update

Tags: boot, package-management, upgrade, 22.04

I use Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on a Lenovo IdeaPad Flex 5 16IAU7. It functions normal, until today. Now after i boot it it will not show the login-screen but a black screen (the encryption before will show normal and i enter my passphrase, but then nothing after that will show).

I can enter as normal through the recovery-mode (unfortunatley it shows no older kernel versions to enter the laptop with).

I checked the latest installed updates, which were installed 10 hours ago (where everything worked as normal still):

`Upgrade: libmutter-10-0:amd64 (42.5-0ubuntu1, 42.9-0ubuntu1), mutter-common:amd64 (42.5-0ubuntu1, 42.9-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 (42.5-0ubuntu1, 42.9-0ubuntu1)`

Any ideas how i can revert these updates or repair the boot-problem any other way? If any more information is needed please tell me and i will provide those informations!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem on Dell Lattitude 5531 Laptops. I fixed it with a newer kernel:

apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04

Some guys recommend adding nomodeset to your Grub-Config, but that is only a workaround and messes with multi monitor setups.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the recommendation, i will try to install a newer kernel and report back here if it worked :)

Comment: Hey thank you it worked! I had to manually install Wifi-drivers again but that was a problem before also and worked without problem :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use Live medium of Ubuntu and use [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Instructions are easy to follow. Select "recommended repair" & the process is automated and hence it should be fixed easily.

Alternatively, you can see the following link:
[How to install the Boot-Repair tool in an Ubuntu live disc?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc)

Comment: Hey, boot-repair didnt work for me, thanks for the idea!