# Grub Rescue after installing Ubuntu

Tags: grubrescue

Today I tried updating Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 14.04. The installtion went fine so I restarted my computer and it came up with a grub rescue> prompt! I have no idea what to do and I am no Linux pro(In fact I first heard about it a week ago:)). Please help now I can't even access windows right now and I need to get some work done, PLEASE HELP!

Comment: How did you upgrade from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Please check [Grub rescue prompt, repair grub](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub)

Answer (score 2):

Don’t worry, do you have the livecd/usb there? Use it to start a live environment, and connect to a wireless network. Then open google and type boot-repair, the first link on my search it the [Ubuntu community help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), there you can find these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal. To paste it in the terminal, copy like you usually do, and paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, so you don't need to write it.

A small window opens up, select recommended repair. 
You have more instructions in the community wiki page for advanced options with the program.

Comment: If you don't have a live enviroment, you can download the boot repair disk from here: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair 
boot-repair &
```

This does not yet work in 14.04 because the files for Trusty are not yet available. As I have the same problem, I will try to fix it by creating the boot repair disk.