# Grub resue error insmod normal File not Found

Tags: 12.04, grub2, windows

I have a Dual Boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Using Disk Management in Windows, I deleted the Ubuntu partition, but when i restart my computer, I'm getting `Grub Rescue` Command.

I Tried `ls (hd0,msdos6)` and when I type `insmod normal`, it says `file not found`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-install the Grub using the instructions mentioned here:- [Grub Install](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd#.Uz6B0vllHuM)

Afte fixing the boot issue you can go ahead and you can remove Grub by referring the link:- [Remove Grub](http://www.wikihow.com/Uninstall-the-Grub-Bootloader-from-a-Dual-Boot-XP-System-With-an-XP-CD)

Comment: I corrupt a 12.04 install overwriting it with a 16.04 and the provided "Grub Install" link worked first try with no errors (windows and mem-test partitions intact).

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have faulty or old version of BIOS which can't handle large files. So you need some external third party software to resolve the issue. I would recommend you to make bootable usb for Boot-Repair or Rescatux(I recommend this).You can easily find them by searching. A link from sourceforge for boot-repair https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/  and Rescatux https://sourceforge.net/projects/rescatux/  They may help in fixing the lost grub path or installing a new grub if you want.