# Grub Error: Unknown filesystem(Tried with Boot-Repair also, Unable to resolve it)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 13.04, live-usb, grubrescue

I have a dual boot in laptop which consisting of Ubuntu along with Windows7,
But my laptop is showing the error Grub Error: Unknown filesystem when booting.

I tried everything in the web and followed the below links
[How to fix "error: unknown filesystem. grub rescue>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/fixing-grub-error-error-unknown-filesystem)
[Grub rescue prompt, repair grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub)

but i am not getting the Partion on the disk and i tried the boot repair with help of live USB which the ubuntu installed in it.
after installation of "boot repair" software, i am not getting the "recommended repair" option in it.

But by generating the Create a bootinfo summary i got the below link as
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11307381/

how i have to get out from it.

Please help me to boot my laptop.

Thank you

Vny Neo

Comment: I don't think Ubuntu has installed properly. How did you install Ubuntu?

Comment: it doesn't look like you have multiple partitions on the only disk "ubuntu has detected". Be careful when you re-partition.  You should probably backup anything of importance before doing anything more.  Message me for more direct help.

Comment: From the Past 1 year i am using the dual boot, ubuntu along with windows 7.
Now only i am facing this problem, i think that the ubuntu file system is completely corrupted or lost.