# Boot failure after updation

Tags: 14.04

I have got updates in ubuntu and after restart I'm getting a tab titled 'gnu brub version 2.02beta2-9ubuntu1.7'. This tab says minimal bash like line editing is supported and a "grub > is also there.

What should i do to fix this problem??

Comment: when I used 'ls' command it shows secure boot forbids loding module from (hd1,gpt4) /boot/grub/x86-64-efi/ls.mod

Comment: Make sure secure boot and fast boot are disabled in bios

Answer (score 0):

Check the error.

1.You have initramfs error ?

2. which type of error shows ?, Blank screen or restating again and again.

In Starting time check the Grub config. `Press e` after check the image file location. If you can't find it. go next.

3. To get the boot CD / installation media and goes to rescue option. and repair your OS.
4. [Grub rescue prompt, repair grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub)

Check the ABOVE LINK YOU CAN FIND MORE.