# Why does my computer keep displaying the GRUB menu when it starts up?

Tags: boot, grub2, startup

Yesterday I tried turning on my computer. It led me into this grub menu and I have no idea how to get out. I can't use my computer anymore due to this. What should I do? Do I type in a command or something?

Comment: When in the grub menu look below it, do you see the timer counting down?

Comment: Press Enter to select Ubuntu as first highlighted item. Press Down Arrow to highlight different options and then press Enter to select one.

Comment: When I start it, it only shows a command line that says grub... nothing else. What do I do?

Comment: Take a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub

Comment: ***Please do not repost questions.***  If you don't understand something in an answer, please identify as such by commenting on the answer itself.  (I have merged your 'other' question and this one because they are the same core problem/question).

Answer (score 1):

## Five keys you can press at Grub Menu

This write-up is from ([omgubuntu.co.uk - Five keys to show Grub menu Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/key-to-show-grub-menu-ubuntu)) which nicely lays out what you can do at Grub menu.

[image: Five Keys Grub]

### 1. Shift

Ubuntu does not display the GRUB menu by default. To see GRUB during boot you need to press the right-hand <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during boot.

### 2. Up/Down Arrow Keys

When you are at the GRUB menu you can use the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> arrow keys to select other operating systems and kernel configurations display in the menu. When you’ve selected the one you wish to highlight press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot it.

### 3. <kbd>e</kbd> for Edit

There may be times you need to edit a boot command,

Use the arrow keys to select a boot option and hit the <kbd>e</kbd> key to that entry’s boot options by hand.

You may need to do this to run a specific boot parameter, pass a kernel flag, adjust the run time level or set the frame buffer mode.

When you’re ready to boot with your modified changes press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>.

### 4. <kbd>c</kbd> for Command Line Mode

Press the <kbd>c</kbd> key at the GRUB Menu to switch into `CLI Mode`. From here you can do a wealth of things, including changing menu entry names, fixing a broken install, or booting into a custom kernel configuration.

### 5. <kbd>Esc</kbd> Key

Tap the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key at any time to return to the main GRUB Menu screen. Should you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> at the editor or command line screens all configuration changes you made are discarded and you’re plonked back at the main menu interface.

Comment: When I start it, it only shows a command line that says grub... nothing else. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Type in `ls` to make GRUB show you all disks/partitions that are currently installed. Then find out which partition is the one with the `/boot/` folder by typing in `ls  (hdX,gptY)/boot/` (replace X and Y with actual disks/partitions). When you found it enter the command `configfile (hdX,gptY)/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This should take you to the GRUB2 entries.