# Black screen with blinking cursor when trying to dual boot Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have a Dell Inspiron 5566 that dual boots Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I recently ran a Windows update and when I tried to boot Ubuntu I got

```
error: unknown filesystem.
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

instead of Ubuntu booting. I was able to fix it by finding the correct partition and setting it from the instructions found here [Grub rescue prompt, repair grub](https://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub). Ubuntu booted fine. I got an error when running `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` but I don't remember exactly what it was.

When I restarted to make sure Ubuntu would continue to boot properly all I got was a black screen with a white blinking cursor in the upper left-hand corner. No buttons work other than ctrl + alt + delete, which makes the computer reboot. I have tried holding shift while booting a few times and one time it gave me a screen with GRUB followed by the cursor in the upper left-hand corner, but every other time it has just given me that black screen with the cursor. When holding shift did work, I still was unable to type anything as far as I could tell. I also saw somewhere to try hitting alt + F4 while on the black screen, but that didn't give me any results either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this? Preferably something that doesn't include something that will lead to data loss as I have important work documents saved there. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Clone your drive to protect those important documents before performing repairs, and consider, one this is solved, a backup system with verification to multiple locations (local + cloud).