Grub doesn't work after I deleted one of partitions
I had 2 Ubuntu versions installed in dual boot. Deleted one of them. Ran update-grub. However, after reboot I have the grub shell instead of the boot menu. How do I fix it?

If you had multiple OSes installed that used grub, they'll each have had their own within /boot/grub on the respective partitions for later stages of grub, but stage 0 of grub exists either on MBR or your ESP, so if you delete the partition of the controlling grub you'll find yourself in grub rescue; is that what happened???. Before deleting a partition, you should ensure the grub of the partition you won't delete has its stage 0 active/installed (ie. grub-install)

This question is similar to: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The duplicate I tagged is (I believe; ie. grub rescue is I gather where you ended up due to partition deleted of the controlling grub) for a different cause but ~same situation (if my understanding of your situation is correct; you gave few specifics include no product/release details, nor what you meant by grub shell (grub rescue??) etc) where fix in that I believe will work

@guiverc as much as I understand, the problem in my case is that the files for the later stages are missing, while in that other question it's because of the 0 stage?

Stage 0 is the part of grub that is OUTSIDE of the partition; thus can get overwritten by installing windows, or in your case the controlling grub had its later stages deleted when you deleted the partition where it was contained...  You left yourself with later stages of grub (in the Ubuntu partition you still have) without any pointer to that partition (your pointer was to the wrong grub I'm betting), thus your situation (as I see it) is equivalent to windows taking away grub stage 0 control...  (stage 0 is grub rescue & most importantly pointer to partition where later stages are)

@guiverc as much as I understand, these are completely opposite.

Are you stuck in grub rescue??   If so your grub relates to the deleted Ubuntu partition, and likely not the grub for your installed OS... The command you mention update-grub only updates the later stages of grub; to re-write stage 0 you use grub-install (often done prior to deleting a partition JUST to ensure the OS you're using controls boot)  Otherwise try https://askubuntu.com/questions/192621/grub-rescue-prompt-repair-grub

@guiverc if Windows overwrites it you just boot to Windows immediately without grub, right? Just trying to understand how this works.

You're stuck in grub rescue I bet; which is because you deleted the later stages of grub & thus the stage 0 pointer is pointing nowhere (deleted partition).  Your existing install has all stages of grub in /boot/grub except stage 0; but booting was controlled (I'm betting) by the other Ubuntu system (the one you deleted).. thus why you're stuck at grub rescue (for the deleted OS). You've provided no Ubuntu details; but contrast the grub package/version with deleted Ubuntu system, OR what you'd expect for your wanted system (assuming releases differed it'll confirm what I'm saying)

@guiverc ok thanks.
